# Using/Calling Google Sheet's embedded File Import function in google apps script

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, import, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Is there any way to call Google Sheet's `File import` function in `Apps Script`? I'm trying to import a csv file from a `google drive folder` to a google sheet. But I want to be able to set up an `automated trigger` to import a csv file with the same name regularly from the same google drive folder.

I'm aware that I can write an import function myself. And I actually wrote such function based on someone else's code I found on github. But the import function I have is very slow since it contains loops. Plus, parsing the entire csv file using the script is very slow. So I only want to use Google Sheet's embedded import function. -> I tried it and it's way faster than import a file using my script.

Answer (score 0):

The menu commands are only available via the user interface. From a script, you can convert CSV files to Google Sheets format using [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive). First, enable the service (v2 of the API) as described on the page. Then in the Apps Script, proceed as follows:

```
var fileId = '0B.......jQ';  // Id of the CSV file
var newFile = Drive.Files.copy({title: 'Converted File'}, fileId, {convert: true});
var newFileId = newFile.id;
```

Now you have a converted file in your Google Drive (with the name 'Converted File'), and the variable `newFileId` contains the Id by which you can access this file using the methods of SpreadsheetApp. In particular,  you can get its contents and put them elsewhere.